# Python 2.7.6 File "<stdin>" error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was running python 2.7.6 version on my mac. Here are my codes:

```
sum = 0
for x in range(101):
    sum = sum + x
print sum
```

After I ran this code, I got syntax error said File `"<stdin>"`, line 3
    print sum.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Please add the **full text** of the error to the body of your question.

Comment: Are you running this as a script?  Or typing this in interactively in the interpreter/shell?

Comment: You are running this in interpreter and there should be line break before `print sum`

Comment: unrelated: `sum` is a built-in function in Python. Don't shadow builtins without a consideration.

Comment: @MattDMo Sorry, I am very new to the forum and I do not understand what is "full text of the error".

Comment: @zehnpaard I am using the python in terminal to run this code.

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia Thanks, I just noticed that I did not jump out of the for loop to use the print function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your error, it looks like you're running those lines from the interactive shell. In that case, please add a line break after expression sum = sum + x (tested on ubuntu terminal) :

```
>>> sum = 0
>>> for x in range(101):
>>>     sum = sum + x
... 
>>> print sum
```

This should stop the error. Note that the interactive shell requires line breaks where Python scripts don't.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you should probably add that you're expecting that OP is running this code in the interactive prompt.

Comment: This is really wrong, there is no rule like your answer. You don't have to line break after expressions.

Comment: Try this in terminal of linux and then comment any thing. If you try to write anything in without line break terminal consider it in loop. Try once then comment..!!

Comment: Python blocks of code are denoted by line indentation, it's not about that. You probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you tried this in Terminal..?? please try it once and if i am wrong you can downvote.

Comment: @ritesh: I think your answer is most likely correct, but it **is** misleading to users new to Python if you don't explicitly mention that this requirement for a line break is specifically tied to using Python interactively from the shell/terminal/command prompt/IDLE, and **not** when you're running the same lines from inside a script/module.  I think that's a necessary clarification before I can upvote the answer...

Comment: Yeah i agree thats why i've mentioned in my answer that code tested in ubuntu terminal. I think it should be up voted again.

Comment: I'll upvote, you okay if I edit to add a bit more explanation?

Comment: @Ritesh Hey, thanks for your response. This really solved my problem. I just noticed that I did not jump out of the for loop to use the print function.